# Session not sending correctly through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, session

I have the following code that I thought worked correctly, but it turns out the users session is not being sent correctly. Let's say I was on trying to make a post, it does not take my id, it takes the id of the last user who registered for my site. Why would this be?

I have this as my `$userid` variable and it should be taking my session. I am initializing the session at the top of the page.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
             $("#submit_announcement").on("click", function () {

             var user_message = $("#announcement_message").val();
                //$user = this.value;
                 $user = $("#approved_id").val();
                $.ajax({ 
                    url: "insert_announcements.php", 
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                           "user_id": $user,
                                        //"message": user_message
                                        "user_message": user_message
                            },
                    success: function (data) {
                           //  console.log(data); // data object will return the response when status code is 200
                             if (data == "Error!") {
                                 alert("Unable to get user info!");
                                 alert(data);
                             } else {
                                 $(".announcement_success").fadeIn();
                                 $(".announcement_success").show();
                                 $('.announcement_success').html('Announcement Successfully Added!');
                                 $('.announcement_success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
                             }
                         },
                         error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                             alert(textStatus + "|" + errorThrown);
                             //console.log("error"); //otherwise error if status code is other than 200.
                         }
                     });
                 });
             });
```

PHP and Form

```
$userid = ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ? $_SESSION['user'] : "" );

try {
    //Prepare
     $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
     if ($user_stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM users")) {

        $user_stmt->execute();
        $user_stmt->bind_result($user_id); 

        if (!$user_stmt) {
            throw new Exception($con->error);
        }
     }
        $user_stmt->store_result();
         $user_result = array();
?>               
     <div class="announcement_success"></div>
            <p>Add New Announcement</p>
                <form action="" method="POST" id="insert_announcements">
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $userid; ?>" id="approved_id" name="user_id" />
                    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="announcement_message" name="message" class="inputbarmessage" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
                    <label for="contactButton">
                        <button type="button" class="contactButton" id="submit_announcement">Add Announcement</button>
                    </label>
                </form>
```

UPDATE: PHP file to show an example

```
// $announcement_user_id= $_POST['user_id'];
$userid = ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ? $_SESSION['user'] : "" );
$announcement_message= $_POST['user_message'];
$test = print_r($_POST, true); 
file_put_contents('test.txt', $test); 
//var_dump($announcement_user_id);

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "", "");
$stmt2 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO announcements (user_id, message, date) VALUES (?, ?, NOW())");
    if ( !$stmt2 || $con->error ) {
        // Check Errors for prepare
         die('Announcement INSERT prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($con->error));
    }
    if(!$stmt2->bind_param('is', $userid, $announcement_message)) {
        // Check errors for binding parameters
        die('Announcement INSERT bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
    }
    if(!$stmt2->execute()) {
        die('Announcement INSERT execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt2->error));
    }
        //echo "Announcement was added successfully!";
    else
    {
         echo "Announcement Failed!";
    }
```

Comment: I'm already initializing the session at the start of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're selecting *all* of the users:

```
SELECT `id` FROM users
```

So when you get one record from that result, it's probably going to coincidentally be the latest record in the table.

You're trying to bind a parameter to i:

```
$user_stmt->bind_result($user_id);
```

so maybe you meant to have a `WHERE` clause?

```
SELECT `id` FROM users WHERE `id` = ?
```

Though, that seems... unnecessary.  Since you already *have* the ID.  You seem to be posting the ID from client-side, *and* keeping it in session state, *and* getting it from the database.  So it's not *entirely* clear what you're even trying to do here.  But one thing that is clear is that query is going to return every record from that table.

Comment: How would you recommend I do it then? All I want to do is get the user's id from the current session.

Comment: Do I even need that query then since I am getting the session?

Comment: @Paul: Isn't that what you're already doing here?: `$_SESSION['user']`  If you have the user's ID when they login, store it in a session value.  Then use that session value on other pages.  All you need to do is make sure that the session is started at the beginning of every page that uses it.

Comment: So could I just take that query out and change my AJAX data to read.. `"user_id": $userid,` ?

Comment: @Paul: It's not clear what you're accomplishing by posting a user ID in AJAX in the first place.  If this is the ID for the current logged-in user, track it in session.  Definitely don't rely on an identifier sent via AJAX because the user can send *any* ID they want, effectively impersonating other users.

Comment: I may be doing it the wrong way, I'm not entirely sure. What I am trying to accomplish is to send the id of the user that is logged in, so that it is sent to a db I have, so that it shows the message was from them.

Comment: @Paul: Then definitely *do not* send it from client-side code.  That would allow the user to impersonate any user they want.  Track the user's identity server-side in the session.  When the user logs in, store the user's ID in the session.  Then on any page that needs it, get it from the session.  (Exactly as the first line of code in the PHP in your question does.)

Comment: Please clarify if I am thinking what you are advising. I should remove my `SELECT` query. Leave the session code `$userid = ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ? $_SESSION['user'] : "" );` , but then how do I send that `SESSION` in my ajax to call to get it to my db?

Comment: @Paul: You *don't* send the session from client-side code.  Session is maintained entirely server-side.  When you need to insert a record into the database and associate it with the current logged-in user, you get the ID of that user from the `$_SESSION` array.

Comment: I'm completely confused on how I can actually do that though.

Comment: @Paul: When the user logs in, store their ID in the session.  Something like: `$_SESSION['user'] = $someUserIDValue;`.  Then on later pages when you need to use the ID, get it from session: `$theUserID = $_SESSION['user'];`.  As long as `session_start()` is included at the top of both pages, any value you store in the session on one page will be available in the session on the other page.

Comment: I updated my question to show my session class that I have at the beginning of every page..... Aren't I already getting the current session with this line of code `$userid = ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ? $_SESSION['user'] : "" );` I just don't know how to get that and send it to my db, so that the id is added to the table I need it to go into.

Comment: Sorry if some of this sounds trivial. I am just trying to learn it, so I don't run into this again.

Comment: @Paul: The code you've posted doesn't use that `Session` class, so I don't see how that's even relevant. (Though I do recommend using it to abstract the dependency on the session.) Either way, it's *really* not clear where you're stuck. And it really sounds like you should start by walking through some PHP tutorials, particularly any which involves a user logging in to the site. I really don't know how to be more clear in my description. When the user logs in, set the value in the session. When you need to use the value, get it from the session.

Comment: I am getting the session though. When I var_dump `$userid`, I get the correct id. The part I am stuck is how to get that into my db. You said not to send it via AJAX, so I don't know how to put that into a query and send, when I am sending everything else via AJAX to the query that inserts it into the db.

Comment: @Paul: AJAX has nothing to do with a database query.  Send the user-supplied values in AJAX, get the user's ID from session, and use all of those in your database `INSERT` statement.  So when you're binding values to your `INSERT` parameters, bind some from AJAX input and one from session.

Comment: Ok great, this is the part I am stuck on and somewhat confused. So if I only send user-supplied values. I only send the message via AJAX and then add this...`$userid = ( isset( $_SESSION['user'] ) ? $_SESSION['user'] : "" );` in my PHP file that my AJAX is calling to. Then in my PHP file I use the `$userid` variable as my bind_param and it gets sent like that? I have added my PHP file to show what I mean.

Comment: PERFECT! It worked great! I appreciate you tolerating my ignorance and helping me through it! This will help me out a bunch in other areas! Thanks!